# Adding location to crawling tweet

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, tweepy, geocode

I want to crawling Python data on Twitter include result location, name, created_at, status, keyword, the details is located in Indonesia which only several city such as jakarta, bandung, etc. But I find this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "loc.py", line 49, in <module>
location = status.place.name AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: How does the object look that you get back from twitter api? It looks like your api call does not return anything

Comment: According to the [reference documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/geo-objects) , not all of these values and fields are always guaranteed to be returned (i.e. they are optional), so if your code always assumes that they are present, you may see this kind of error.